# XML parsing returns null when using Android Fragments for honeycomb

Tags: android

I am trying to parse an XML file and fetch its contents and display in a ListFragment. It is working fine for 1.6 to 2.2 SDK(Without fragments). When I try to use fragments such that on clicking one fragment listitem, it must display another ListFragment beside it by parsing an XML, I get response as null. Has anyone worked on XML parsing using Fragments in Android? If there are tutorials related to this, kindly post the link for the same

Comment: Your question is too generic to give a meaningful response.

Comment: Alright, to be more specific, I have a ListFragment containing 4 ListItems coffee,beaches,chocolates and countries.On clicking each listiem, it must give me another ListFragment beside it showing list of items of that category. This list is in the XML format. I need to parse that XML and display it in the form of ListFragment.I am currently getting XML response as null and Node Length 0.

Answer (score 0):

If this XML is a static xml, create a StringArray in the resource file and use that, parsing XML is not very efficient.
If the XML is a static file and you still want to use it to parse it. Please post the code used for parsing